# Remover todas as folhas de uma árvore binária em pascal

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, pascal, árvore-binária

estou tentando implementar um algoritmo que remova todas as folhas de uma árvore binária, isto é, nós que não tem nenhum filho. Eu até consigo remover mas não consigo deixar os "pais" desses nós com referencia nula. Ai quando chamo a função para exibir a lista, dá erro de loop infinito pq nunca chega no nil. Alguém pode me ajudar? Segue codigo:

```
  program arv;

  procedure InsereD(var t:arv; x: integer);
  var p: arv;
  begin
     new(p);
     p^.item:= x;
     p^.dir:= nil;
     p^.esq:= nil;
     if t = nil then t:= p
     else
        if x<t^.item then InsereD(t^.esq, x)
        else InsereD(t^.dir, x);
   end;

        procedure EmOrdem(t:arv);
        begin
            if t<> nil then
            begin
                EmOrdem(t^.esq);
                writeln(t^.item);
                EmOrdem(t^.dir);
            end;
        end;

        procedure removeFolhas(p:arv);
        var v:integer; t:arv;
        begin
            if(p = NIL) then exit;

            removeFolhas(p^.esq);
            if((p^.esq = NIL) AND (p^.dir = NIL)) then
            begin
                t:=p;
                v := p^.item;
                p^.item := 0;
                dispose(t);
                t:=nil;
                writeln('folha ',v,' removida'); 
            end;
            removeFolhas(p^.dir);
        end;


    var t1  : arv;
    begin
        clrscr;
        write('Criando uma arvore. Digite quantos itens serao inseridos: ');
        read(n);
        if (n = 0) then t1:= nil
        else begin
            for i:=1 to n do begin
                write('Digite o ',i,'o numero:');
                readln(x);
                InsereD(t1, x);
                end;
        end;

        writeln('Imprimindo em Ordem:'); //teste de Ordem
        EmOrdem(t1);

        writeln('Removendo folhas:');
        removeFolhas(t1);

        writeln('Imprimindo em Ordem de novo:'); //teste de Ordem
        EmOrdem(t1);
        readln();
    end;
```

Comment: Eu usaria 0, mais simples que nil...

Answer (score 0):

Basta ajustar a recursão. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
procedure removeFolhas(p:arv);
var v:integer; t:arv;
begin
    if(p = NIL) then exit;

    removeFolhas(p^.esq);
    removeFolhas(p^.dir);

    if((p^.esq = NIL) AND (p^.dir = NIL)) then
    begin
        t:=p;
        v := p^.item;
        p^.item := 0;
        dispose(t);
        dispose(p);
        t:=nil;
        p:=nil;
        writeln('folha ',v,' removida'); 
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Continuo tendo problemas de exitcode=216, por conta de não atribuir Nil as novas folhas.

Comment: Alterei o codigo da descrição para que veja o programa completo. Obrigada pela ajuda ;)

Comment: Veja as alterações que fiz no código. Acredito que possa lhe ajudar

Comment: Eu não vejo setando o valor do item `pai^.esq := NIL` ou `pai^.dir := NIL`